# Rails/ruby transform string to UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I'm currently doing:

`DateTime::strptime('12/11/17', "%d/%m/%Y")` => `Fri, 12 Nov 0017 00:00:00 +0000`

But I want `Mon, 11 Dec 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually want the month name to be different?

Comment: the month should be december yes

Comment: Dec 11th is a Monday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snipped should do what you are looking for (using ruby 2.3):

```
DateTime::strptime('12/11/17', "%m/%d/%y").strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S UTC %Z") 
#=> "Mon, 11 Dec 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00"
```

Comment: you can use `%y` and it will convert 2 yr to 4 yr.